# how to create and concatenate dynamic variables in PHP?

Tags: php, dynamic-variables

In this php code, during a `while` loop, I was hoping to use later 3 variables called `$menu_1`, `$menu_2`, and `$menu_3`. Is this possible in PHP?

```
while($parent_row = mysql_fetch_array($parent_result)){
    $menu_ = "";
    $menu_ . $i = "\n\t$('#menu_" . $i . "').hover(function () {";
}
echo $menu_1;
echo $menu_2;
echo $menu_3;
```

Comment: You should study PHP arrays http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php and then google for "PHP dynamic variables". First result is always on php.net (PHP is such a popular language), right in the docs.

Comment: Thank you. I think what I am doing is kinda tricky I need pieces of jquery / css inserted in precise places. Thank you for the links I am new to PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use curly brackets for that:

```
${'menu' . $i}
```

but I strongly advise you just to echo the stuff you need inside the loop.

Plus, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated - go either the PDO or the `mysqli` way please.

Comment: I sure will look into PDO or mysqli right away.  I have to be honest the `old` way sure kicks a$$ even compared to classic asp code.

Comment: This works great and answered my question above. I will be using arrays for sure!! And changing my database calls. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever somebody says "dynamic variables" it's a big red flag.  You can do them but it's a bad idea 99% of the time.  What you're probably looking for is an array.  If you write:

```
$menus = array();
while($parent_row = mysql_fetch_array($parent_result)){
    $menus[$i] = "\n\t$('#menu_" . $i . "').hover(function () {";
}
echo $menus[1];
echo $menus[2];
echo $menus[3];
```

You'll get what you're after without delving into the maintenance headache & potential disaster that dynamic variable names would give you.  You can also easily loop over `$menus` which makes things nice when you suddenly have 2, 4 or 40 different elements.

Comment: Thanks. I will probably go with this for the majority of the work. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Just use brackets. Look at this example:

```
<?php

$one = 1;

$suffix_one = "_".$one;
$suffix_two = "_2";

$base_1 = "VALUE ONE";
$base_2 = "VALUE TWO";

echo ${"base".$suffix_one}." , ".${"base".$suffix_two};

?>
```

Result:

```
VALUE ONE , VALUE TWO
```

Obviously, like other users said, you'd better use arrays. But i answered anyway for your information.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use arrays instead?

```
$menu[$i] = "\n\t$('#menu_" . $i . "').hover(function () {";
```